# Android application not launching with Appium

Tags: automated-testing, android, appium, mobile-automation

I have downloaded the latest Appium Desktop to inspect the different elements for automating an app. I was able to launch the calculator app on my Android phone but was unable to launch an app that I have installed from the APK.

These are the variables that I have used to launch the apps on my phone :

```
  "platformName":
  "deviceName": 
  "appPackage":
  "appActivity":
```

Comment: You should check out the `DesiredCapabilities` for Appium. By reading the documentation and following the correct set of procedures, you will get it running in no time.

Comment: You need to specify what happened - just mentioning unable to launch could mean a lot of things could go wrong. Did you get an error? Did the code execute without doing anything? Please edit the question with description of the issue

Answer (score 1):

You could also share the code that you are using - like the `setUp` method - to be easier to detect what pieces are missing.

Just by looking at those variables, you're providing I could say that it would not hurt to pass also the `platformVersion` and the path to your local `.apk` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);       
capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);       
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);       
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);       
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package");       
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity); driver =       
Driver().setDriver(new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" +      port + 
"/wd/hub"), capabilities));
```

This code should work !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup everything as explained in the official Appium website. [Link to the page](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/index.html).